# How to make notification clickable?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

My notification can show but I would also want it to be clickable so that when it's clicked it would open the same activity it came from.

```
public void acceptNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(RequestConfirm.this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("PEOPLE HELPER");
        builder.setContentText("Your request has been accepted");

        Intent intent = new Intent(RequestConfirm.this, BroadcastFragment.class); //creates an explicit intent
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(RequestConfirm.this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(RequestConfirm.this); //adds the intent
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);  //put the intent to the top of the stack
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //(id, flag) //creates a pending intent
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent); //adds the PendingIntent to the builder
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) RequestConfirm.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

Comment: you need to set pendingintent to notification builder

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
Intent gotoIntent = new Intent();
gotoIntent.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), "FULL CLASS NAME");
PendingIntent contentIntent = null
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                    (int) (Math.random() * 100), gotoIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now set in notification Builder:

```
.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

To start the activity, you have to use the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityClass.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 
        0, 
        intent, 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build()); when you want to show the notification. By clicking that pending intent will be started.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
  notificationBuilder.setContentText(msg);
  notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
  notificationBuilder.setVibrate(vibrationPattern);
  notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
  notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , hope this will helpful for you.

```
NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(CurrentActivity.this);
Notification notify;
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(CurrentActivity.this, 0,
new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notify = builder.setContentIntent(pending)
                 .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message1))
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logop).setTicker(excep).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                 .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("your Notification title")
                 .setContentText(message1).build();
```

CurrentActivity refers to Activty/class that belong to your service Activity/class and nextActivity refers to Activity/class where you want to move.